# MongoDB timestamp now

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I check the current timestamp in MongoDB?

Currently I use a query that looks like:

```
   "last_visit": {
     "$lt": NumberLong(1373779876) 
  }
```

I store that query, and then I have a cron job that makes it run every minute.

If one of my users hasn't logged in since some timestamp, I can know it.

But the NumberLong generated isn't right, as I am currently using time() - 14days via PHP, the resulting NumberLong should be the result of something like:

timestampNOW - someTimestamp (that I generated in PHP)

My current solution stays an absolute date in the past, instead of a relative date such as timeRIGHTNOW - 14 days.

I believe I need a native Mongo command within my query...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for, but I think there are two options:

a) You want to construct a query **using php** that asks mongodb for all users that haven't logged in the last two weeks

```
<?php
// two weeks ago. note that time() returns number of seconds, not milliseconds
$date = (time() - (14 * 24 * 60 * 60)) * 1000;
// construct query: { "last_visit" : { $lt : $date } }
$query = array( 'last_visit' => array( '$lt' => $date ));
$cursor = $collection->find($query);
// you can now iterate $cursor
?>
```

b) You want to perform a mongodb query **in javascript** ('native Mongo command')

```
db.Foo.find({"last_visit" : {$lt : ISODate().getTime()}});
```

calling `ISODate` will create a new `ISODate` object representing the current time, and [`getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) will return the number of milliseconds since the UNIX epoch. I don't know how you can pass that query to the PHP mongodb driver, but it should be straightforward.

Comment: Instead of ``(time() - (14 * 24 * 60 * 60)) * 1000`` you should use ``(strtotime("two weeks ago") * 1000)``. Not every day is ``24 * 60 * 60`` minutes!

Comment: Also, you can't pass the ISODate().getTime() trough the driver. Your solution in pure PHP is what I would do.

Comment: In UTC, the length of a day is constant, and in many contexts that is what people expect: user hasn't logged in within the last 336 hours (save for leap seconds). In most scenarios, I don't want to consider DST here. Passing JS queries through the driver should be possible, but probably requires `command` or `execute`, sth. like http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php

Comment: Yeah, but don't use JS if can avoid it, it is a big performance hit. And he said two weeks, not 14 days ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Current timestamp rounded to whole second:

`Timestamp(new Date().getTime()/1000,0)`

Timestamp 14 days ago:

`Timestamp((new Date().getTime()-(3600*24*14*1000))/1000,0)`